# Getting remotely executed commands output in a veriable using expect in perl

Tags: perl

I have a password variable `$pw` and a command variable `$cmd`.

```
$pw=UNIX password of a remote machine.

$cmd=Command to be executed in the remote machine.
```

now if I run the command using `back-tick`
I will be able to get some value in the output variable.

now if I want to run the same command through a expect I how to achieve the same. I mean how to get the out put of the command run through a expect in a variable.

my expect function is like:

```
  sub expt($$){
my $cmd;
my $timeout;
    ($cmd, $pw)=@_;
$expect = Expect->new;
$expect->raw_pty(1);
printDebug("Running the command under expt");
$expect->spawn($cmd)
    or die "Cannot spawn $cmd: $!\n";
$expect->expect($timeout,
            [   qr/password:/i, #/
                sub {
                    my $self = shift;
                    $self->send("$pw\n");
                    exp_continue;
                }
            ],
            [qr/Are you sure you want to continue connecting \(yes\/no\)?/
                , sub { my $self = shift;
                                   $self->send("yes\n");
                                   exp_continue; }],
             [qr/Unix password \(user\):/
               , sub { my $self = shift;
                                   $self->send("pw\n");
                                   exp_continue; } 
             ],                      
                  );

$expect->soft_close();
   return 0;             
 }
```

And I am calling the function like

```
expt($cmd,$pw);
```

By doing this I am able to execute the script in the remote host but my requirement is to store the output of the remote host in a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `Net::SSH::Expect` ? It would be more close to the first method: you "just" need to do something like that:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
        host => "myserver.com", 
        user => 'myuser', 
        raw_pty => 1
    );
$ssh->run_ssh() or die "SSH process couldn't start: $!";
($ssh->read_all(2) =~ />\s*\z/) or die "where's the remote prompt?"
$ssh->exec("stty raw -echo");
my $output = $ssh->exec($cmd);
```

Have a look at `Net::SSH::Expect` pod documentation, it is quite extensive.

Comment: because I am matching some more expect pattern and my script is not doing ssh at all it is login to machins with some other tool but those tool also need password so I am here reducing the no of password typing while performing some task. The ssh i have given is just an example the real script is only passing passwords to multiple patter match and I need the output whenever there are remote hosts executions.

Comment: Be precise. We can only answer the question you ask ;) You can still use this module and play with "send", "read_all" and other methods.

Comment: Lets say I passed a command like "pogo --namespace yap run --job-timeout 720000 --timeout 360000  -I @yap.ws.yosprod.sp1 'for i in `seq 1 10`; do echo $i;sleep 3;done'" and this command will run on multiple hosts and the host will get determine on the fly but I want the output of these command in a veriable

Comment: Then put this one-liner script in a file, execute it remotely and get its output via `Net::SSH::Expect`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help your suggestion is really good but I am afraid I can't put that on my script because the logic is much bigger which can't be accomplish with this.

Comment: Just remember, that with either this module or through traditional Expect, big things will be slow, as every command as to be waited by the Expect engine. If you want to go fast, maybe having a look at something more `Net::Telnet`-like, but then you would need to do all the heavy lifting.